# Use select command in Selenium IDE testing tool for selecting one option from dropdown list

Tags: selenium-ide

We are using Selenium IDE testing tool in our web application. I am confused in using select command; I need to select one value from a drop down using select command.

In select ( selectLocator,optionLocator ) what can we give in place of selectLocator and optionLocator for selecting one option from dropdown list?

Answer (score 2):

In the command select (selectLocator, optionLocator), 'selectLocator' is the Id of the drop down from which the value is being selected and the 'optionLocator' is the value being selected.

For eg: say a drop down having `Id="//select[@id='type'"` with values like 'TypeA, TypeB, TypeC,...'. If you are selecting 'TypeA' from the drop down, your command should go like this:

```
selenium.select("//select[@id='type']", "label=TypeA");
```

I hope this will solve your problem.
:)